# Code inside $(document).ready() function does not work for AJAX callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have Javascript code for date picker like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date").Datepicker({
        Field: '#date',
        Format: "YYYY/MM/DD",
        date: true,
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
    });
});
```

Date element works correctly. But when I edit my post, I create date element with AJAX. When I click date element again, the datepicker does not work and also does not show any error to me.

AJAX code :

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function () {
     $.ajax({
        type: 'put',
        url: 'edit',
        data: $(".form").serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ajax_div').html(result);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: you need to put the code inside ajax success handler. Also note that, id should be unique.

Comment: thanks, Id is unique and ajax work correctly .but the datepaicker in not work

Comment: can you share the ajax call code also

Comment: I edit my post and share ajax code

Comment: You need to recall the DatePicker() initialiser on newly created elements. The document.ready will only do ones on the page at the time. It won't re-run again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to recall your date picker code after you dynamically append the HTML code. To fix this, put the code in a function:

```
function enableDatePicker() {
    $("#date").Datepicker({
        Field: '#date',
        Format: "YYYY/MM/DD",
        date: true,
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
    });
}
```

Call it immediatly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    enableDatePicker();
});
```

And call also after you appended the HTML:

```
$(document).on("click", ".edit-btn", function () {
     $.ajax({
        type: 'put',
        url: 'edit',
        data: $(".form").serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            $('#ajax_div').html(result);
            enableDatePicker(); // Call it again
        },
    })
});
```

Also, the another problem I see is that you are calling `.Datepicker()` on an element with an id `date` which is stating that there can only be a one element with that `id` (as an HTML dom should have `id` unique). So try to use a class selector and then call the `.Datepicker()` on that.

Answer (score 3):

It doen't work because your document is already complete. AJAX is loaded after that.

You could use

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete()
```

see here the full doc:
http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/

PS. i never used it i just found out about it.

### EDIT

it should be like this:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    $("#date").Datepicker({
        Field: '#date',
        Format: "YYYY/MM/DD",
        date: true,
        format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
    });
});
```

Comment: can you convert my ajax function to .ajaxcomplete()?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('body').on('focus',"#date", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
      date: true,
      format: 'YYYY/MM/DD'
    });
});​
```